# How do I append a value to formData on event? (blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, form-data

I have this code for the moment ->

```
$('#file').fileupload({
    formData: {
        valueThatChangesOverTime: value,
        staticValue: 0
    },
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    autoUpload: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        $('#importFilesBtn').on("click", function () {
            // Set value to formData.valueThatChangesOverTime
            data.submit();
        })
    },
    done: function (e, data) {

    }
});
```

As you see in my comment I want to append a value to the formData object on a click event but I can't figure out how to do it. It always stays with the initial value.

Has someone done this before and how did you solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like answering my own questions but for the clarity of this question I thinks it's best. I finally found the solution. Instead of trying to "update" the formData I append it myself in the `add:` event, like this.

```
add: function (e, data) {
        $('#importFilesBtn').on("click", function () {
            data.formData = {
                valueThatChangesOverTime: myNewValue,
                staticValue: 0
            };
            data.submit();
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If the add function is being called as reference to the fileupload options object, then the `this` will be set to point to the object.
With that assumption, the following should work:

```
add: function (e, data) {
    var fileUploadObj = this
    $('#importFilesBtn').on("click", function () {
        // Set value to formData.valueThatChangesOverTime
        fileUploadObj.formData.valueThatChangesOverTime = 'foo'
        data.submit();
    })
}
```

edit: another option.
I cant think of another way to reference the object from within but another approach would be to take advantage of object linking. Feels a little dirty, but it'd work.

```
//some external object
foo = {"changeThisValue":"value"}
$('#file').fileupload({
formData: {
    valueThatChangesOverTime: foo,
    staticValue: 0
},
...
add: function (e, data) {
    $('#importFilesBtn').on("click", function () {
        // Set value to formData.valueThatChangesOverTime
        foo.changeThisValue = 'bar'
        data.submit();
    })
}
```

caveat is, now whatever is handling formdata has to deal with an object instead of directly the value.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. "this" is in this case the html element and therefor this.formData is undefined.